# Why are the futures prices different from the buying power effect?

Tags: futures, online-trading

I'm beginner,
When I buy 1 share of a $10 stock, the buying power effect/costs = $10+Commission
but in futures, the cost is very different from the quoted price, is futures quoted price different from stocks?  and how it is calculated?
[image]

[image]

Comment: With futures, you only have to put up a small percentage of the notional value of the futures contract as margin.

Comment: [Learn About Futures Margin](https://www.thebalance.com/all-about-futures-margin-on-futures-contracts-809390)

Comment: What is this trading platform? Is it the TD Ameritrade Mobile App?

Comment: @Flux I hesitate to answer these questions, Couldn't it be considered like advertising a product?  by the way, yes this shot is from what you said